# Are the alternating pentultimate and the $2$-alternating pentultimate isomorphic?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

Consider a physical puzzle which is in the shape of a dodecahedron where the pieces that move are the face centers and you can slice it through a plane parallel to two opposite faces going through the exact center of the puzzle. (This puzzle also has corners but we will ignore those for this question.) This is called the 'pentultimate'. Now consider the further restriction where moves must alternate between clockwise and counterclockwise and always rotate by exactly $72$ degrees. Surprisingly this now forms M12 (or M11 if you require one of the faces to be held in place, the distinction isn't relevant to this question.)

Now consider a variant of this mechanism which is also an alternating pentultimate but each move rotates $144$ degrees instead of $72$. My question is, is there an isomorphism between these two puzzles where the moves of one of them arrive at the same positions corresponding to the results of moves of the corresponding position on the other one? And if so, is there a simple way to describe what the corresponding position on the other puzzle is to one on the first? We have gathered some numerical evidence suggesting that there is such a correspondence: The puzzles correspond to the same group and have the same number of steps in god's algorithm, but what the correspondence could be is far from clear. It seems to be part of some subtle self-isomorphism of M12.

Comment: Isn't this just the Galois automorphism of Q(sqrt(5)/Q) ?  The face centers are the vertices of three mutually perpendicular golden rectangles; changing the golden ratio to its algebraic conjugate yields three new golden rectangles but in another orientation, and takes adjacent pairs of vertices to adjacent-to-antipodal pairs.